# Questions on noise cancelling headphones

Tags: noise

I was doing some research on how noise cancelling headphones work. They work by inverting sound waves 180 degrees out of phase to cause destructive interference.

While I was researching, I encountered active noise cancellation and passive. It is very confusing for me that there were two.

Are there two types or is there is just one and "passive" is actually just isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noise cancelling headphones work by inverting the polarity of sound waves 180 degrees out of phase (λ/2) to cancel out the sound. If a sound wave meets its mirror image, they both result in silence.

For instance, 1 - 1 = 0.

Noise cancelling headphones have a mic, dsp (digital signal processor), and a speaker. First, the microphone detects outside sound. Then, the dsp (digital signal processor) calculates and creates an anti phase sound wave. After that, the phase inverted sound wave is mixed into the audio stream which includes your music. Next, the speaker plays the sound out of phase.

This in result, reduces background noise. Noise cancellation mainly reduces consistent low frequency sounds. But, it is very difficult to reduce fast high frequency sounds and sounds that vary and change.

Passive is just a term for normal headphones.

*Passive is a very old term and it is not the latest method.
The latest method for cancelling sound is destructive interference (active noise reduction) (ANR), which involves creating the phase inversion of the unwanted noise signal.*

Comment: You forgot the most important part - mixing inverted signal into actual audio stream.

Comment: @Maple I updated it,  thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty interesting tech. It's surprising that they work as well as they do, and this says something for the power of modern low power DSP chips, as well as the associated battery tech that powers these things.

"Active cancellation" as others have said is trying to sum an antiphase signal to cancel ambient noise. Anyone who has tried to do this, even in the pure electronic domain, knows that it is not easy! Small phase delays will degrade your performance significantly. If we are dealing with analogue electronics, these delays are typically nanoseconds. With acoustic signals, we are talking milliseconds.

I suppose that the success of these devices depends on a few things:

1. being able to mount the sense microphone very close to the ear (on the shell of the microphone).
2. being able to characterise the acoustic difference between the mic and the ear and so do some signal processing to optimise the cancellation to cancel out the small phase difference between the two, and also (probably) the frequency-dependent acoustic isolation of the headphone itself.

I have a fairly old (first gen) set of Sony cans which already work quite well. They have iterated and improved several times since then, although I haven't tried the more recent models, I imagine these must be very good.

When you add in the integration of bluetooth, the use of digitally generated voice cues to guide the user through pairing, different operation modes and so on - these things are really impressive pieces of technology.

Answer (score 0):

Passive noise cancellation is just isolation. This can be found by simply googling “passive noise cancellation.”

Active noise cancellation is as you described, implemented by producing a sound that is ideally 180 degrees out of phase from the source to “cancel” out the original sound. This is easier said than done.

Comment: @watercastle I have seen noise cancelling earbuds and also noise cancelling headphones. The headphones work a lot better because they combine passive and active cancellation. They are almost a must if you work in one of these "open office" type places. You can put on some type of non-distracting music and then tune out everyone around you when you need to concentrate. They work well on long airline flights, also. They can cancel a lot of the airplane noise.

Comment: @watercastle Those are just marketing rubbish terms. And not all active noise cancelling types actually try to cancel sound waves by generating inverse sound waves, but simply by adding pseudorandom white noise to mask out what comes through after the passive attenuation.

Comment: Modern TV newscasts have experts at home in an echo chamber with their microphone far away and the system cancels their voice very often.

Comment: Passive noise cancellation is a really sneaky term and is a scam. Active noise cancellation is real marketing.

Comment: @Justme that is just the noise that is generated by simply turning the DSP circuitry on, similar to when you switch between radio channels in your car, you hear white noise. All active noise cancelling headsets do at least attempt to generate an inverse sound wave, it is just extremely difficult to create the opposite wave as all sound waves are not perfect sine waves and you only have microseconds to  create a opposite.